# Not be able to load grandchildren node using v-treeview - Vuetify

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm having difficult time to load grandchild node using v-treeview from Vuetify. I was able to load child node. What I'm trying to implement is that whenever I click on a node (parent, child, or grandchild) it should load the node whatever I selected. For example, if I select parent node, it should load child node, and if I select child node it should load grandchild node.
The way my database is constructed is that each content have self_id and parent_id. If a content self_id is 1 and parent_id is 0, that means this content is the root/parent node. Moreover, if and a content self_id is 2 and parent_id is 1, whenever I load the content this content will be a child node of content slef_id 1.

I really need help with this one because I've been trying to find some answers but I couldn't find anything that I'm trying to do. Perhaps, there are better ways to to this and if so, please let me know, I'm open to any suggestions!

Here is my code:

```
<v-treeview
   :active.sync="active"
   activatable
   return-object
   :load-children="getChildList"
   :items="contentList" >
</v-treeview>
```

```
active: any = [];

contentList: TreeViewType[] = [];

private async mounted() {
    await api.autoGetAllList()
        .then((Response) => {
          this.getContent(Response);
        });
  }
   

  private getContent(Response: any) {
    Response.forEach((item) => {
      if ( item.parent_id === 0) {
        this.contentList.push({
          id: item.id,
          name: item.title,
          children: [],
        });
      }
    });
  }


  private async getChildList(item) {
   await api.getChildNode(item.id)
       .then((Response) => {
         Response.forEach((data) => {
           item.children.push({
             id: data.id,
             name: data.title,
             children: [],
           })
         })
         console.log(Response);
       });
  }
```

Comment: I think your `getChildList` function is correct and it should work just fine. You don't need to check if selected item is parent or child, one thing is important that item should have `children` key in order to be **loadable** . Here you can see working example [v-treeview](https://codepen.io/bakhti-uzb/pen/JjbRpYq?editors=1010)

Comment: @bakhti_UZB I was able to find a solution. Thank you for your comment!